# What are nqp, nqp-m, rakudo-debug, rakudo-debug-m, rakudo-gdb-m, rakudo-m, rakudo-valgrind-m?

Tags: raku, nqp, moarvm

When I install [rakudo](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo) from source:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:rakudo/rakudo.git
$ cd rakudo
$ perl Configure.pl --gen-moar --gen-nqp --backends=moar
$ make
$ make install
```

it generates the following files in `./install/bin`:

```
$ ls -1 install/bin
moar
nqp
nqp-m
perl6
perl6-debug
perl6-debug-m
perl6-gdb-m
perl6-lldb-m
perl6-m
perl6-valgrind-m
raku
raku-debug
rakudo
rakudo-debug
rakudo-debug-m
rakudo-gdb-m
rakudo-lldb-m
rakudo-m
rakudo-valgrind-m
```

I know that `raku`, `rakudo`, and `perl6` are the the commands used to run a `.raku` script, but what are the other commands and how can I use them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `moar` is the vm (not very useful without a bytecode file)
- `nqp` is for NQP (Not Quite Perl6). Which is a small subset of Raku that is faster / easier to optimize. (No `=` op for example)
  It is the bootstrap compiler for Rakudo.

For the others like `rakudo-m`

- `*-m` means on MoarVM
- `*-j` means on JVM (not installed here)
- `*-js` means on JavaScript (not installed here)

- `*-debug` means, use the version with debugging information
- `*-gdb` means use the version with GNU Debugger information
- `*-lldb` means use the version with LLDB debugging information
- `*-valgrind` means use the Valgrind instrumentation framework (find memory leaks)

So then `rakudo-valgrind-m` means use **Rakudo** compiler with **Valgrind** instrumentation on **MoarVM**.

About the only ones I would use is `rakudo-m`, and `rakudo-j` or `rakudo-js`, and that is only if I had more than just the MoarVM version installed.

Mainly the rest are for people that are working on Rakudo/NQP/MoarVM projects themselves.

Comment: What raiph said  :-)

Comment: @raiph Perl already has mini-perl which they use when configuring Perl. Also NQP has Raku-like semantics. So while saying Not Quite Perl6 is a bit anachronistic, saying Not Quite Perl is further from useful.

Comment: @raiph I have yet to see **any** NQP code that would compile with Perl. Or any Perl that would compile with NQP. Most aren't even close. I have seen plenty of NQP code that would compile as Raku code. In [fib.nqp](https://github.com/Raku/nqp/blob/master/examples/fib.nqp) only 2 out of 9 lines are valid Perl. `sub fib($n) {` and `}`. The first of which is only valid after you enable the relatively new signature feature. Ignoring that, most of the underlying semantics are also different to Perl. So calling it Not Quite Perl only made sense when the name Perl included what is now called Raku.

Comment: @raiph **NQP** means **NQP**. It used to have a reason for those specific letters. That reason is only useful to explain the historical context. Saying that the **P** stood for **Perl6**, while wrong, I think gets people to understand the history better than saying it stood for just Perl. If I could change the CSS so that the 6 was grey on white instead of black on white, I would do so.

Comment: I deleted all my 2021 comments here and instead reddited a [virtual unilateral **NQP rename**](https://www.reddit.com/r/rakulang/comments/jmvnf2/comment/gv0f6e8/). which I've just updated. (For a decade I thought calling NQP Not Quite Perl was and remained worse than useless. As Brad noted, the PL `nqp` is different semantically from Perl, like Raku, and even more so syntactically, so "Not Quite Perl" only made a smidgen of sense when Perl included what is now Raku. Brad got and articulated those parts of our common view well, even if it seems to me they must have thought I didn't get theirs.)